# basis for polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, physics, legendre-polynomials

A basis for the polynomials that shows up in physics are the “Legendre polynomials.” The first few, B = {1, x, ((3/2)x^2)-(1/2)}, are a basis for P2. Calculate [3-x+x^2]B.

I understand a basis is the largest set of linear independent vectors, but not sure how it comes to play for this question.

Comment: Hint: find $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $3 - x + x^2 = a \cdot 1 + b \cdot x + c \cdot (\frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2})$.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding hint given by dxiv

In general you can express any (even noncontinuous) function by a linear combination of (orthogonal) basis

here
$$3-x-x^2=\sum_{n=0}^{2}c_nP_n \tag{1}$$

Where $P_n$ are the Lengendre polynomials
Use the orthogonal property of the Lengendre Polynomials given by

$$\int_{-1}^1 P_nP_mdx=\frac{2}{2n+1}\delta_{mn}$$

Where $\delta_{mn}$ is the kronecker delta

Multiply eq(1) by $P_m, \forall m<3$ and integrate

you get

$$\frac{2}{2m+1}c_m=\int_{-1}^{1}(3-x-x^2)P_m\mathrm dx$$

Substitute these $c_m$'s back in eq(1)